# CSS odd even with 2 cols

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My html is like this:

```
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
```

and there are 2 articles in one line with float and i want them to change the color like:

```
blue green
green blue
blue green
green blue
```

how can i do that with css?

Comment: Like a blue and green checkerboard?

Comment: Just to aid the question, I believe this is the pattern he is after: http://codepen.io/mrchris/pen/bigeK. I've used classes, a solution using nth-child would be nicer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are four `article`s in a pattern, so some offset of `4n` ought to do the trick. This seems to work ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5nKv/)):

```
article {color:blue}
article:nth-child(4n-1), article:nth-child(4n-2) {color:green}
```

If you don't like minus, plus also works just the same ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5nKv/1/)):

```
article {color:blue}
article:nth-child(4n+2), article:nth-child(4n+3) {color:green}
```

---

Just to explain the entire logic, it's a matter of shifting the `4n` pattern:

```
                   4n-3    4n-2    4n-1
#   COLOR   4n     4n+1    4n+2    4n+3
-- ------  -----  ------  ------  ------
 1  blue    -       0        -        -
 2  green   -       -        0        -
 3  green   -       -        -        0
 4  blue    1       -        -        -
 5  blue    -       1        -        -
 6  green   -       -        1        -
 7  green   -       -        -        1
 8  blue    2       -        -        -
 9  blue    -       2        -        -
10  green   -       -        2        -
11  green   -       -        -        2
12  blue    3       -        -        -
13  blue    -       3        -        -
```

`-1` and `+3` are congruent mod 4, as are `-2` and `+2`, so these refer to the same elements (although the value of `n` is technically different for each).

You could even swap it around and color `4n` and `4n+1` blue ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5nKv/3/)):

```
article {color:green}
article:nth-child(4n), article:nth-child(4n+1) {color:blue}
```